# complexity in finding the number of times each character is present in a string

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
input_string = "foobaarfoooobaaaarfo"
count_dict = {}
for char in input_string:
    try:
        count_dict[char]=count_dict[char]+1
    except:
        count_dict[char]=1
print(count_dict)
```

is this the best algorithm with complexity O(N) for the given problem statement

Comment: yes, your algorithm runs in O(n). what's best is subjective.

Comment: well, the best is indeed subjective but clearly, exceptions aren't good for performance. You can use a defaultdict(int) instead of a dict, and then remove that ugly try/except block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `O(n)` is the best you can do.

It is necessary to visit each character to count them all.

However, in terms of python implementation, you will probably get better performance, and more readable code using the specialized collection `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
input_string = "foobaarfoooobaaaarfo"
counter = Counter(input_string)
print(counter)
```

Comment: @ saiteja pakalapati，I think so.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that `O(N)` is the best you can do.

I did a simplification for your program. You do not have to use try and raise exception here.

```
input_string = "foobaarfoooobaaaarfo"
count_dict = {}
for char in input_string:
    count_dict[char] = count_dict.get(char, 0) + 1
print(count_dict)
```